# PHP & MySQLi - Show selected value two time in drop-down list

Tags: php, html, mysqli, drop-down-menu

I created my profile page with show all data in form from MySQL. All data is show rightly on form and also in drop-down list. But the problem is selected value is shows two time in the option list.

Here is the my code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
     <option value="">Select Country
         <?php
            //Get country list from Country master
            $qry = "select * from country_master";
            //Execute query
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
            //Assigned fetched array to $Country
            while($country = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
              echo "<option value='$country[1]'>$country[1]</option>";
              //Compare User Country with country list. $row[4] is the country column in user table
              if($row[4] == $country[1])
                 echo "<option value='$country[1]' selected='selected'>$country[1]</option>";
            }
         ?>
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: bhavin just needed if else condition in while loop

Comment: @A-2-A right, he could at *least* upvote me for the mishap if he's gonna do that -_-

Comment: See no matter what answer will be choose, but at-least it will be the first correct and descriptive answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your `while` code like below:-

```
while($country = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //Compare User Country with country list. $row[4] is the country column in user table
    if($row[4] == $country[1]){
        echo "<option value='$country[1]' selected='selected'>$country[1]</option>";
    }else{
        echo "<option value='$country[1]'>$country[1]</option>";
    }
}
```

**Note:** In your code first option is created and then condition is checked, that's why two times it will show the selected option.

Comment: Sorry A-2-A, It's happen by mistaken.

Comment: No problem, sorry for my bad words too:)

Comment: @A-2-A Just edited your code for more readability, I hope that's fine. :-)

Comment: One issue in yur code brother option inside the option chk my answer

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to the issue you are facing is provided by **A-2-A**.

**Additionally** 
You are nesting all of your looped options inside your "Select Country" option.  you should remove the last`</option>` tag before the `</select>` tag and move it after "Select Country" like so:

`<option value="">Select Country</option>`

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your issue:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
 <option value="">Select Country
     <?php
        //Get country list from Country master
        $qry = "select * from country_master";
        //Execute query
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
        //Assigned fetched array to $Country
        while($country = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
             echo "<option value='$country[1]'".($row[4] == $country[1] ? " selected" : "").">$country[1]</option>";
        }
     ?>
  </option>
```

The problem was that you had echoed the selected option additionally to the non-selected option. Now, it adds the 'selected' attribute if the option should be selected. (Based on your condition)

Answer (score 1):

It should be set up like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
     <option value="">Select Country
         <?php
            //Get country list from Country master
            $qry = "select * from country_master";
            //Execute query
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
            //Assigned fetched array to $Country
            while($country = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

              //Compare User Country with country list. $row[4] is the country column in user table
              if($row[4] == $country[1]){
                echo "<option value='$country[1]' selected='selected'>$country[1]</option>";
              }
              else{
                echo "<option value='$country[1]'>$country[1]</option>";
              }

            }
         ?>
      </option>
</select>
```

Because you need to check if the value is selected, then if it isn't display the data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

- using option inside the option.
- second you just need to print selected attribute instead of printing complete option.

**Example:**

```
<option value="">Select Country 
</option>
<?php 
//Get country list from Country master $qry = "select * from country_master"; 
//Execute query 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry); 

//Assigned fetched array to $Country 

while($country = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 


if($row[4] == $country[1]) {
$selected = 'selected=""';
}
else{
$selected = "";
}
?>

<option <?php echo $selected;?>   value='<?php echo $country[1];?>'>
<?php echo $country[1];?>
</option>
<?php
}
?>
```